# In ARM V7 architecture - is there a way we can block direct switching (changing CPSR) from Secure SVC to Monitor.

Tags: armv7

In ARM V7 when I am running in Secure SVC mode, I could directly change to Monitor mode just by changing Mode bits in CPSR. I want to ensure, mode switch from Secure SVC to monitor happens only through SMC call / exception. Is it possible in ARM v7 architecture by any way.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no architectural way of enforcing this. The most you can do is carefully audit all uses of `msr` and `cps` in the non-monitor code (and possibly writes to SCR as well) to look for mode/security state switches.